# Records with extra properties: sparse table or EAV?

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-attribute-value, sparse-matrix

I have a model that already has a couple dozen of columns that will be filled most of the time. Now I need to add fields that might be different each time.

what's the best approach? I don't like the EAV pattern. I don't like the idea of having a sparse table either, especially considering how these extra properties could be very different.

Example:

```
WorkOrder:
PK id
FK assigned_to
FK contractor
DATE expected_completion
DATE actual_completion
... (many more)
```

Now I want to add properties like:

```
ep_1 (extra_property)
ep_2
ep_3
ep_4
... (many more)
```

These extra properties can be wildly different from record to record, and most of the time there will be a limited number of them, but there are no guarantees.

Think of records as:

```
id  |  assigned_to  | contractor  | ... | ep_1   | ep_2  | ep_3 | ... | ep_n
1   |  2            | 3           | ... | XYZ    | NULL  | NULL | ... | 23
2   |  3            | 5           | ... | NULL   | 1     | NULL | ... | NULL
3   |  2            | 1           | ... | NULL   | 0     | NULL | ... | NULL
4   |  4            | 1           | ... | XYZ    | NUL   | NULL | ... | 45
```

I want to be able to list, filter, and search records as if those extra properties were actually columns, eg: I should be able to make queries like `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ep_n > 20` and `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ep_1='ABC'`

What's the best solution to this?

Comment: Without knowing all the properties you expect to encounter, it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: @OMG This would make the question too localized. Just think of them as data. I should be able to make queries like `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ep_n > 20` or `SELECT fields FROM table WHERE ep_1='ABC'`

Comment: I don't agree with your expectations - it's a design that will work you into a corner, when the alternative is to properly model tables & incorporate the necessary joins.  Can't model those tables without knowing what they are...

Comment: @OMG I'm sorry, but I am afraid that's not possible. These are properties users might be adding on the fly (including the "key"). It would be a maintenance nightmare. And I would have dozens of tables with little data in them.

Comment: Some of it is foresight, but this is why database design is not iterative.  With proper normalization, maintenance should be *less of a hassle*.  To be frank, it sounds like you've already made your decision & want others to agree with you.

Comment: @OMG If you can point out a solution to the problem that doesn't involve creating dozens of new tables I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I can't say you'll need dozens of tables, but you will need tables - it all depends on what the business & it's rules are.  I don't understand your need to keep this to as few tables as possible - that guarantees denormalized data, which increases the likelihood of *bad data*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What database? With SQL Server for instance, you can consider using [Sparse Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) which are optimized for sparse tables. For EAV modeling I recommend reading the whitepaper on the subject from the SQL Server customer adviser team: [Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability](http://codesmartinc.com/codesmartinc/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/semantic_db_modeling.docx). Many of the recommendations apply to other vendors too, are not SQL Server specific.